# Java threading synchronization for I/O bound and CPU-heavy operations

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

The task is - need to process multiple I/O streams (HTTP downloads) with some CPU-heavy operation. Ideally would like to have full bandwidth and CPU 100% used. Of course - heavy CPU processing is slower then internet download. Unprocessed data could be cached to disk.  Are there any existing Executors in ASF or other components providing this functionality? If not - what's the best way to achieve this? Thinking of having 2 thread pools one for `Internet-To-Disk` and other for `Disk-To-CPU-To-Disk` operations.

EDITED:

I'll clarify my question:

2 thread pools: `Internet-To-Disk` and `Disk-To-CPU-To-Disk` is producer/consumer approach itself. The question was HOW to make sure I've selected right number of threads for `producers` and `consumers`? Same code will work simultenously on different boxes, arches with different number of cores and different bandwidth. How to make sure I've chosen right number of threads so 100% bandwidth and 100% CPU are consumed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that CPU processing is going to be the main bottleneck of your system, the number of threads for CPU processing should be, at the least, set to the number of CPUs or cores available.

I/O part is probably not going to use much CPU at all, but you may want to allocate a fixed pool of few threads (equal to, or less than, the number of cores) to prevent excess thread context switching for simultaneous I/O streams.

You may also set the number of threads for CPU processing to a number slightly bigger than the number of cores, if your CPU processing threads do not always use 100% of CPU from start to finish. For example, if they may do some I/O or access some shared resource in the middle of processing.

But as with any system, the ideal number of threads will greatly depend on the nature of your program. You can use tools like JVisual VM (bundled with JDK) to analyse how threads are utilised in your program, and try different thread setting variations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [producer-consumer](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Threads/ProducerconsumerforJ2SE15usingconcurrent.htm) for this purpose. Use as many producers and consumers as its needed to fulfill the needs.

Comment: Okay, the idea was to load both bandwidth and CPU as much as possible (this is not a problem that after couple of weeks of work (hundreds of millions HTML pages should be downloaded) download will stop and only CPU processing will keep running. Basically - the question leads to - HOW TO BALANCE both pools (or producers/consumers) to load 100% system fully. How to automatially find the right number of threads for that balance?

Answer (score 0):

If your CPU stage is more intensive than the download time, why not just download the data as you are able to process it.  That way you can have multiple Internet-To-CPU-To-Disk processes.  By skipping a stage it may be faster, and it will certainly be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for a producer-consumer architecture : one thread pool to process the data (managed by an ExecutorService), and one or more threads to download the data from the internet.

The data to be processed would be put into a bounded blocking queue (ex: LinkedBlockingQueue), so that the downloading threads would only fetch data when required (that is, when a computing thread is able to process new data). Plus, this structure guaranteed thread safety and memory publication.

Comment: If you have the threads do the download and processing, you will never have too many downloading or processing threads waiting for each other.

Comment: Threads waiting for permission to put new items in a blocking queue are put in WAITING mode ; they're cheap and don't consume any CPU time.
And, for the sake of architecture clarity, I'd rather have two distinct pools, one for downloaders, one for data processing : each can be configured and tuned independently. A self-feeding "producer-consumer" pattern is... strange.